# How to install Latest version of Apache Solr on Ubuntu and how to uninstall

Tags: 14.04, apache2, solr

How to install Latest version of Apache Solr on Ubuntu and how to uninstall (remove) completely

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### An older version of solr

An older version of `solr-tomcat` and `solr-jetty` is in the Ubuntu Universe repositiories, **for a newer version see below**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

---

For Tomcat

```
sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat
```

For Jetty

```
sudo apt-get install solr-jetty
```

Open the URL `http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/`, if your tomcat is listen on port 8080.

---

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove solr-tomcat
sudo apt-get remove solr-jetty
```

---

### A newer version of solr

Use the manual installation for a newer version, check the latest version [here](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/) and replace the version in the commands below, for old versions check [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/)

```
cd ~
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/5.3.1/solr-5.3.1.tgz
tar xzf solr-5.3.1.tgz solr-5.3.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
sudo chmod +x install_solr_service.sh
sudo ./install_solr_service.sh solr-5.3.1.tgz
```

Open the URL `http://your_server_ip:8983/solr`

<sub>[More details](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04)</sub>

---

Uninstall via

```
sudo service solr stop
sudo rm -r /var/solr
sudo rm -r /opt/solr-5.3.1
sudo rm -r /opt/solr
sudo rm /etc/init.d/solr
sudo deluser --remove-home solr
sudo deluser --group solr
```

For a better explanation of the uninstall steps, read my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/680695/367165).

Comment: Seems to me the latest release is [5.3](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/5.3.0). 14.04 has [3.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/solr-tomcat).