# How to uninstall Solr

Tags: solr

I used [this DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install Solr 5.3.1 in my system.

It worked fine. Now I wish to uninstall it. How do I carry that out?

All the existing articles seem to specify using `apt-get` but I can't find any `solr-*` packages to remove.

I also checked the tarball downloaded during installation and could not make out how to uninstall it or if it has an uninstall script just like the install script.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have found the following definitions in `install_solr_service.sh`

- `SOLR_EXTRACT_DIR=/opt`
- `SOLR_SERVICE=solr`
- `SOLR_VAR_DIR=/var/$SOLR_SERVICE` –>>>– `/var/solr`
- `SOLR_USER=solr`
- `SOLR_INSTALL_DIR=$SOLR_EXTRACT_DIR/$SOLR_DIR` –>>>– `/opt/solr-5.3.1`
- `SOLR_DIR=${SOLR_INSTALL_FILE%.tgz}`
- `SOLR_INSTALL_FILE=${SOLR_ARCHIVE##*/}`
- `SOLR_ARCHIVE=$1` –>>>– `solr-5.3.1.tgz`
- `ln -s $SOLR_INSTALL_DIR $SOLR_EXTRACT_DIR/$SOLR_SERVICE`
- `cp $SOLR_INSTALL_DIR/bin/init.d/solr /etc/init.d/$SOLR_SERVICE`

therefore

```
sudo service solr stop
sudo rm -r /var/solr
sudo rm -r /opt/solr-5.3.1
sudo rm -r /opt/solr
sudo rm /etc/init.d/solr
sudo deluser --remove-home solr
sudo deluser --group solr
sudo update-rc.d -f solr remove
sudo rm -rf /etc/default/solr.in.sh
```

and **check** the commands above **twice** before executing. One wrong space and you can reinstall your system.

Comment: Just want to make sure that it is safe to manually remove it?

Comment: That's the only way. **;)** But you could read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165) first.

Comment: @callmekatootie "tarball downloaded during installation " = manual install so the removal is manual too ;-) The removal part seems correct to me. Just be careful with the commands. (hitting enter just after typing `sudo rm -r /var/` would be problematic ;) )

Comment: Ok. I noticed that I get warning about `group solr no longer has any more members` and when I try installing again, I get the message `Warning: The home dir /home/solr already exists. Not copying from `/etc/skel` - should that also be part of the uninstallation steps?

Comment: Both is ok, I have improved the answer. You could remove the home folder `sudo rm -r /home/solr`

Comment: You are missing this, if you want to re-install it again. sudo update-rc.d -f solr remove and sudo rm -rf /etc/default/solr.in.sh

Comment: @SuneelKumar thank you brother, you saved my arse. Comment in my delete script includes a link here and "but NOTE THE COMMENT from SuneelKumar". I have edited the answer to reflect these necessary commands :)

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: how to remove installed solr service?